# ggplot - bar plot for two variable from the same data frame

Tags: r, ggplot2

I need to generate a plot with bar graph for two variables.

I can create a column graph for one variable like below

```
df <- head(mtcars)
df$car <- row.names(df)
ggplot(df) + geom_col(aes(x=car, y=disp))
```

how to go about getting a chart like below ( created in excel) - essentially I need add bar plot of more than one variable.

[image]

Comment: Please see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099219/plot-with-2-y-axes-one-y-axis-on-the-left-and-another-y-axis-on-the-right

Comment: @Linus - thanks. I will refer to that part for the secondary axis question.

Comment: Edited the question to only one part

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With `ggplot` you need to convert data to long format so that one column defines the color and one column defines the y value:

```
library(tidyr)
df$car = row.names(df)
df_long = gather(df, key = var, value = value, disp, hp)
ggplot(df_long, aes(x = car, y = value, fill = var)) +
  geom_bar(stat = 'identity', position = 'dodge')
```

[image]

Comment: how can we bring the legend to the top centered horizontally and set the y-axis label to the variable names !!

Comment: I'm sure if you search the `[ggplot2]` tag for those questions you can find excellent solutions!

Comment: just an unrelated comment - I see that you are using `=` rather than `<-`. Is this generally accepted practice ?

Comment: It's uncommon, but it's just fine. I prefer it so I do it.